# Upgrading from SPS 2003 to MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

If there are extensive modifications made to search.aspx in SPS 2003, will they get lost when you upgrade to MOSS 2007?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, they will NOT be lost.

> **Search.aspx**
>
> The Search.aspx file is not changed or
>   overwritten during the Office
>   SharePoint Server 2007 upgrade
>   process. Customizations you have made
>   to this page should continue to work
>   after upgrading.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms564715.aspx